# HSM SSL cert auto-renew

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, hardware-security-module

I am new to HSMs. We are looking at AWS CloudHSM OR Thales Luna Cloud HSM as providers. Getting the cert is pretty straightforward, but how to auto-renew? Has someone done this before?

I found these docs, but it looks like there is no tool for automatically requesting SSL cert renewal with AWS, and I would have to write a script for it...? Situation is similar with Thales.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/using-aws-cloudhsm-backed-certificates-with-microsoft-internet-information-server/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/ssl-offload-enable-traffic-and-verify-certificate-windows.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/key_mgmt_util-reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, a HSM is just secure storage for private (or symmetrical) keys.  While the vendor may provide tools for manipulating the keys and even for creating simple certification request or self-signed certificates, these are just for very simple use cases and don't provide any Certificate Lifecycle Management - which seems to be, at a basic level, what you're after.

Your first link shows the certificate being enrolled from a CA.  The CA may provide client software which can be installed on the subscriber which may manage enrolment and renewals for you.

For example, if you use a Microsoft CA, then Windows has a built-in client, controlled by group policy, which can automatically renew certificates.

If you use a commercial CA, you will need to investigate what they offer.  They may have a client which you can install to manage the certificates.  Alternatively, there are standard protocols, such as [ACME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Certificate_Management_Environment), [CMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Management_over_CMS), [CMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Management_Protocol), [EST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enrollment_over_Secure_Transport) or [SCEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Certificate_Enrollment_Protocol) which these CAs may be able to work with.  You'll then need to install clients for those protocols on your server.